# Popup to use the entire screen width and height - windows apps

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am trying to create a custom dialog with lots of TextBlocks, TextBox's and Buttons. After a fair bit of research, I have implemented a 'Popup' within my Grid which has a bit of my form UI.

How can I center the popup dialog in the page. I have tried using the horizontalOffset and VerticalOffset but still the popup is populated below the button I am using to populate the popup.

I also have two more question if you can guide me in the right direction:

- Is this the right way to populate custom dialog's in windows apps (for tablet)?
- How can I reuse the popup from another page.?

Thanks in advance
rao

MainPage.xaml

```
 <Button
               x:Name="bFour"
               Content="Popup with buttons and text"
               Height="75" FontSize="32"
               Click="bFour_Click"/>


        <Popup x:Name="Popup1"
               IsOpen="False"
               LayoutUpdated="Popup1_LayoutUpdated"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <StackPanel Background="Blue"
                        Width="5000"
                        Height="5000">
                <TextBlock Text="One" FontSize="54"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Two" FontSize="54"/>
                <Button x:Name="bClosepopup" Content="Close Popup" Click="bClosepopup_Click"/>           
            </StackPanel>

        </Popup>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 private void bFour_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Popup1.HorizontalOffset = r.Next(100, 100);
        //Popup1.HorizontalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Width - gdMain.ActualWidth) / 2;
        //Popup1.VerticalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Height - gdMain.ActualHeight) / 2;
        //Popup1.Height = ActualHeight;
        //Popup1.Width = ActualWidth;
        Popup1.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void Popup1_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (gdMain.ActualWidth == 0 && gdMain.ActualHeight == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        double ActualHorizontalOffset = this.Popup1.HorizontalOffset;
        double ActualVerticalOffset = this.Popup1.VerticalOffset;

        double NewHorizontalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Width - gdMain.ActualWidth) / 2;
        double NewVerticalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Height - gdMain.ActualHeight) / 2;

        if (ActualHorizontalOffset != NewHorizontalOffset || ActualVerticalOffset != NewVerticalOffset)
        {
            this.Popup1.HorizontalOffset = NewHorizontalOffset;
            this.Popup1.VerticalOffset = NewVerticalOffset;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing 2 properties:

- [PlacementTarget](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.placementtarget(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Placement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.placement(v=vs.110).aspx)

Try with those and see if the result is better.

EDIT 1:

Unfortunately Popups in Windows apps do not have the same properties as normal WPF applications. Here is the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227842). Popups do not seem to be the right way to achieve what you are trying to do.

---

For your 2 other questions:

- Is this the right way to populate custom dialog's in windows apps
  (for tablet)?

  Refer to the following [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/apps/hh738363.aspx).
- How can I reuse the popup from another page?

  I would suggest you use [MVVM Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) and the [MVVM Messenger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx) to trigger popups from your main page. [MVVM Light Toolkit Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/mvvm-light-toolkit-fundamentals)

Comment: Hi Kotix, can you give any examples which i can follow

Comment: Since your question contains more than one actual question, I would suggest you try out some things and ask more specific questions about problems you encounter. For examples of MVVM projects, I will edit my answer with a great video tutorial made by the main developer of the library.

Comment: Could you suggest any example on placement target and p;lacement usage.

Comment: The `PlacementMode` enum [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.placementmode(VS.85).aspx) is extremely explanatory

Comment: I tried to add 'Placement' in the XAML but it said property not found in type ''Popup'